# Laravel Mix multiple entry points generates one manifest.js

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-mix

I currently have a problem trying to use multiple entry points in my Mix file.

```
// Mix frontend resources.
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .extract([
        'jquery', 'bootstrap', 'aos', 'lity',
    ]);

...

// Mix app resources.
mix.js('resources/assets/app/js/app.js', 'public/app/js');
```

I have three entry points in my Mix file. One for frontend, backend and my "public app" file. The code above stores my frontend `vendor.js` and `manifest.js` file inside `public/app/js` when it should be inside `public/js`.

When I then try to reference

```
<script src="{{ mix('js/manifest.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ mix('app/js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

it throws webpack errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    at __webpack_require__ (manifest.js?id=09ecc9b…:55)
    at Object../node_modules/vue/dist/vue.common.js (app.js?id=6431fd7…:sourcemap:28709)
    at __webpack_require__ (manifest.js?id=09ecc9b…:55)
    at Object../resources/assets/app/js/app.js (app.js?id=6431fd7…:sourcemap:37900)
    at __webpack_require__ (manifest.js?id=09ecc9b…:55)
    at Object.0 (app.js?id=6431fd7…:sourcemap:38015)
    at __webpack_require__ (manifest.js?id=09ecc9b…:55)
    at webpackJsonpCallback (manifest.js?id=09ecc9b…:26)
    at app.js?id=6431fd7…:sourcemap:1
```

Is there currently a way to use multiple entry points in a Mix file?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In order to create a mix file for backend and frontend each (and other entry points if needed), adjust `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env process.env.section=website NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "cross-env process.env.section=website NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env process.env.section=website NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "admin-dev": "npm run admin-development",
    "admin-development": "cross-env process.env.section=admin NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "admin-watch": "cross-env process.env.section=admin NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "admin-prod": "npm run admin-production",
    "admin-production": "cross-env process.env.section=admin NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  },
```

webpack.mix.js:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

if (process.env.section) {
  require(`${__dirname}/webpack.mix.${process.env.section}.js`);
}
```

create webpack.mix.website.js:

```
let { mix } = require('laravel-mix');

mix
  .setPublicPath(path.normalize('public_html/assets/website'))
  .less('resources/assets/website/less/website.less', 'css/style.css')
  .options({
    processCssUrls: false
  })
  .js('resources/assets/website/js/website.js', 'js/global.js')
;
```

create webpack.mix.admin.js:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix
  .setPublicPath(path.normalize('public_html/assets/admin'))
  .options({
    processCssUrls: false
  })
  .js('resources/assets/admin/js/admin.js', 'js/global.js')
  .less('resources/assets/admin/less/admin.less', 'css/style.css')
;
```

This is currently the only way to create multiple manifest files etc. for multiple entry points on different directory levels.

Comment: How to make this work with webpack lazy loading feature?

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day ;)

Comment: Implemented this in Laravel 5.5. The admin and the website compilation works but it overwrites the manifest.json file. Did anyone notice this issue? Any suggestion on what could be the reason behind it?

Comment: This overwrites the manifest, which means one part of your website will never load...

Comment: You can use https://github.com/kabbouchi/laravel-mix-merge-manifest to merge manifest files

Comment: After splitting frontend and admin anyone know how to watch both at the same time rather than watch frontend and manually compile admin whenever required?

Answer (score -1):

Add `"gulp": "^3.9.1"` in your package.jsone file

```
"devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "cross-env": "^3.2.3",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "laravel-mix": "0.*",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "vue": "^2.1.10"
  },
```

and in your webpack.mix.js file add bellow code

```
 const { mix } = require('laravel-mix');
    mix.scripts([
    'resources/assets/js/app.js'

    ], 'public/js/manifest.js')//Combine All JS files into one file
   .minify();
```

and then run bellow command for minify js

```
npm run production
```

{{ HTML::script('public/js/manifest.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('app/js/app.js') }}

Comment: This will not work is you have different entry points on different directory levels. Laravel-Mix lacks this feature still, so I answered my own question with a workaround